# How can I solve this cordova media capture error?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, mediacapture

I'm trying to register a video in my application through the cordova plugin Media Capture. According to the documentation, this is my code :

```
startRegistration(){
    var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
      var i, path, len;
      for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
          path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
          // do something interesting with the file
      }
    };
    // capture error callback
    var captureError = function(error) {

    };
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1});
  }
```

I tried compiling the code but I received the following error :

```
Property 'device' does not exist on type 'Navigator'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What version of ionic are you using?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair Ionic 5.4.6

Comment: I have added an answer. If you already have latest plugin installed then ignore first line.

Answer (score 0):

Its used to work like this in Ionic 1 but not anymore. Now you will need to install `@ionic-native/media-capture` as well.

Skip first command if you already have latest plugin installed.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture
npm install @ionic-native/media-capture
```

After installing you can use this plugin like this

```
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';


constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) { }

...


let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 }
this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
  .then(
    (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(data),
    (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
  );
```

[Here is the link where you can find details](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture)

`Corodva` or `Capacitor` Please follow accordingly. You can find guides for both in this link.

Comment: I tried the solution you posted but I got this error: 
Cannot find module '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx'

I tried removing /ngx from the path. The app crashed at the beginning showing this error:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:162
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/media-capture/index.js (index.js:247)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/service/camera.service.ts (auth.interceptor.ts:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/service/ruby-api.service.ts (env.service.ts:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:19)

Comment: Have you installed this using `npm install @ionic-native/media-capture`

Comment: Yes, I did, according to the documentation